# Executable in Docker image not found

Tags: docker, sh, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm attempting to build a Docker image from a Dockerfile which copies and extracts a `.zip` archive containing an executable (`myapp`, among other files). There is a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script which runs the executable. The `docker build` completes successfully, however when I run the image the entrypoint script fails saying that the executable cannot be found.

```
$ docker build .

Successfully built 890ec2f09ad4

$ docker run 890ec2f09ad4

./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 3: ./myapp: not found
```

I've verified that the executable has been extracted from the archive, and that the command is being run in the correct directory by doing an `ls -l` in `docker-entrypoint.sh` script.

```
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root            45 Jan 20 22:16 docker-entrypoint.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         71473 Jan 20 22:16 myapp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           177 Jan 20 22:16 myapp.ini
```

If I run the same `docker-entrypoint.sh` script outside of the Docker image, next to the executable, everything works perfectly.

I've also tried:

- Running the executable directly from the Dockerfile (Resulted in a similar "file not found" error)
- Using the `ubuntu:latest` base image (Same error)
- Using dos2unix to ensure that the line endings are correct (No change)

What else can I try? I'm new to Docker, and this seems like it should be fairly simple to accomplish, so I'm not sure where I went wrong...

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/
WORKDIR /opt/app/

COPY target/products/myapp.zip .
RUN unzip myapp.zip && rm myapp.zip

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

./myapp
```

Comment: if you access the container while it's running, can you confirm your file is where you expect it to be? `docker exec -it container-name sh` Assuming the unzip operation worked, it looks okay to me.

Comment: What in your myapp? It is single file or tree directories? What is you trying to run?

Comment: @ChrisTurner Just connected to the container, and everything from the .zip archive is in `/opt/app/`, and I verified that the permissions are as expected

Comment: I guess the next thing I would try is changing your entry point to be the absolute location, something like `/opt/app/docker-entrypoint.sh`

Comment: @VolArt The `myapp` file is a single ELF 64-bit LSB executable

Comment: @ChrisTurner Updated to use the full path, and got the same error: `./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 3: /opt/app/myapp: not found`

Comment: Inside `docker-entrypoint.sh` have you referenced `myapp` by the full path too?

Comment: @ChrisTurner Oops, misread your comment. Yes, I just tried using the full path for both, but no luck...

Comment: Unsure sorry dude, looks all fine to me. Shot in the dark, have you tried switching `ENRTYPOINT` to `CMD`?

Comment: @ChrisTurner No worries, thanks for taking the time! I have tried that as well, but no luck there either.

Comment: `ldd /opt/app/myapp` will tell you if there are missing shared library dependencies (that'd be my guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @VolArt for directing my attention to the executable type.

Turns out that the issue was compatibility between the executable (an ELF 64-bit LSB executable, dynamically linked) and Alpine. The solution was to simply use a different base image. I also needed JRE 8 in the end as well, so I settled on the `openjdk:8-jre` base image. (I also needed to manually install `unzip`)

Related posts that helped to nail down the issue:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/883625/alpine-shell-cant-find-file-in-docker
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/
WORKDIR /opt/app/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

COPY target/products/myapp.zip .
RUN unzip myapp.zip && rm myapp.zip

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8081

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

/opt/app/myapp
```